# In the r tidymodels ecosystem is there a collect_metrics() equivalent for a simple fit model that does not use resampling?

Tags: r, tidymodels

In the tidymodels ecosystem, is there an equivalent to `collect_metrics()` that will evaluate model performance on a training dataset without using resampling?

Why?

The `collect_metrics()` function is a lovely way to extract model performance metrics with resampling.  I am teaching and I would love to apply `collect_metrics()` to simple `fit()` models to make the point about how overly optimistic results are when you evaluate on your training data.

Showing the process of fitting the model to the training data and calling model evaluation functions (e.g., `accuracy()` and `roc_auc()` etc. for a logistic model) is a useful but very distracting tangent that I am trying to avoid.  I am thinking I could build a function that would call the "default" `collect_metrics()` metrics on a "model_fit" object but I am hoping somebody beat me too it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two lines via `augment()` and a metric set:

```r
library(tidymodels)
```

```r
tidymodels_prefer()
theme_set(theme_bw())
options(pillar.advice = FALSE, pillar.min_title_chars = Inf)
```

```r
data("two_class_dat")

mod_fit <- 
  logistic_reg() %>% 
  fit(Class ~ ., data = two_class_dat)

# Make your own metric set
some_metrics <- metric_set(accuracy, roc_auc)

# Get predictions on the training set
augment(mod_fit, new_data = two_class_dat) %>% 
  # Evaluate the metric set
  some_metrics(Class, .pred_Class1, estimate = .pred_class)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   .metric  .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 accuracy binary         0.819
#> 2 roc_auc  binary         0.888
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Max.  That is superb.